# unix command to replace string in particular position if it matches pattern in a particular position

Tags: unix, replace

Need a unix script for the below scenario.
I have a text file whose record length is 6683. 
I need to replace position from 2707 to 2713 to '0000000' only if position 2714 is '3'. Other records should not be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what language(s) your script should use, so... tcl (Which is quite nice for text processing, if underappreciated these days).

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
while {[gets stdin line] > 0} {
  if {[string range $line 2713 2713] eq "3"} {
    set line [string replace $line 2706 2712 0000000]
  }
  puts $line
}
```

(I'm assuming your positions are 1-based indexes, not 0-based. Adjust numbers as needed if that's not the case.)